# Computing only the block diagonal of an outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, hessian-matrix, kronecker-product, outer-product

I have a matrix:

$$
v = \begin{pmatrix}
    r_1 & r_2 \\
    s_1 & s_2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I wish to find a numerical efficient way to compute:

$$
O = \begin{pmatrix}
    r_1 r_1 & r_1 r_2 & 0 & 0 \\
    r_2 r_1 & r_2 r_2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & s_1 s_1 & s_1 s_2 \\
    0 & 0 & s_2 s_1 & s_2 s_2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

But I can't find a clean way to compute this.

I could compute the full outer product matrix and then just set the off diagonals to 0, but once I start moving to large v matrices this becomes infeasible.
Another approach would be to compute the outer product of r first, and then the outer product of s, and then stitch it together, but is this really my best option?

To put it all into context: 
I'm trying to compute the Hessian of the softmax function, which is given as:
H = diag(p) - outer(p)
The problem is I do this in Matlab that is horribly inefficient when doing for loops, and furthermore I need to combine this into an anonymous function to use as a preconditioner.

Comment: What is the definition of an "outer product", resp. "outer product matrix"?

Comment: I use the kronecker product of the flattened matrix to calculate the outer product.
So in this case: $outer = kron(vec(v^\top),vec(v^\top)^\top)$